How to handle the renderTags() return in pentatrion
I use pentatrion to install vite to my symfony project. I followed the steps in pentatrion documentation(https://symfony-vite.pentatrion.com/extra/migration.html) but I still get this error:
Return value of Pentatrion\ViteBundle\Service\EntrypointRenderer::renderTags() must be an instance of Pentatrion\ViteBundle\Service\mixed, string returned

This is the error in my log:
[2024-06-20T22:39:48.201801+02:00] php.CRITICAL: Uncaught Error: Return value of Pentatrion\ViteBundle\Service\EntrypointRenderer::renderTags() must be an instance of Pentatrion\ViteBundle\Service\mixed, string returned {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Return value of Pentatrion\\ViteBundle\\Service\\EntrypointRenderer::renderTags() must be an instance of Pentatrion\\ViteBundle\\Service\\mixed, string returned at /.../myapp/vendor/pentatrion/vite-bundle/src/Service/EntrypointRenderer.php:289)"} []
[2024-06-20T22:39:48.303733+02:00] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception TypeError: "Return value of Pentatrion\ViteBundle\Service\EntrypointRenderer::renderTags() must be an instance of Pentatrion\ViteBundle\Service\mixed, string returned" at /.../myapp/vendor/pentatrion/vite-bundle/src/Service/EntrypointRenderer.php line 289 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Return value of Pentatrion\\ViteBundle\\Service\\EntrypointRenderer::renderTags() must be an instance of Pentatrion\\ViteBundle\\Service\\mixed, string returned at /.../myapp/vendor/pentatrion/vite-bundle/src/Service/EntrypointRenderer.php:289)"} []

This is the function in EntrypointRenderer.php:
/**
 * @return string|array
 */
public function renderTags(array $tags, bool $isBuild, bool $toString): mixed
{
    if (null !== $this->eventDispatcher) {
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(new RenderAssetTagEvent($isBuild, $tag));
        }
    }

    if ('link-tag' !== $this->preload) {
        $tags = array_filter($tags, function (Tag $tag) {
            return !$tag->isModulePreload();
        });
    }

    return $toString
    ? implode('', array_map(function ($tagEvent) {
        return TagRenderer::generateTag($tagEvent);
    }, $tags))
    : $tags; // line 289
}

This is the version : "pentatrion/vite-bundle": "^6.3",
{
        "name": "pentatrion/vite-bundle",
        "version": "v6.3.4",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/lhapaipai/vite-bundle.git",
            "reference": "c46fa23e33064e087d178d79be9f117b411fff0c"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/lhapaipai/vite-bundle/zipball/c46fa23e33064e087d178d79be9f117b411fff0c",
            "reference": "c46fa23e33064e087d178d79be9f117b411fff0c",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "php": "^7.4 || ^8.0",
            "symfony/asset": "^4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 || ^7.0",
            "symfony/config": "^4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 || ^7.0",
            "symfony/dependency-injection": "^4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 || ^7.0",
            "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 || ^7.0",
            "symfony/http-client": "^4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 || ^7.0",
            "symfony/http-kernel": "^4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 || ^7.0",
            "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 || ^7.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^3.9",
            "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.8",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
            "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 || ^7.0",
            "symfony/web-link": "^4.4 || ^5.0 || ^6.0 || ^7.0"
        },
        "type": "symfony-bundle",
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Pentatrion\\ViteBundle\\": "src/"
            }
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "MIT"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Hugues Tavernier",
                "email": "hugues.tavernier@protonmail.com"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Vite integration for your Symfony app",
        "keywords": [
            "bundle",
            "symfony",
            "vite",
            "vitejs"
        ],
        "support": {
            "issues": "https://github.com/lhapaipai/vite-bundle/issues",
            "source": "https://github.com/lhapaipai/vite-bundle/tree/v6.3.4"
        },
        "time": "2024-01-25T22:11:09+00:00"
    }

The twig:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22><text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22>⚫️</text></svg>">
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ vite_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
        
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ vite_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
        
    </body>
</html>

Screenshot:



Please share the code involved that could help others to reproduce the problem

Also, https://github.com/lhapaipai/vite-bundle/blob/main/src/Service/EntrypointRenderer.php does not back the error message: must be an instance of Pentatrion\ViteBundle\Service\mixed is not what the return type of that method contains

The code you've shared is not part of the latest version published by the maintainers of that bundle. Please update it

@NicoHaase I make this : composer require pentatrion/vite-bundle, is that not install the latest version ?

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, and share which version of that package you've installed

"This is the version : "pentatrion/vite-bundle": "^6.3"" - no, that's a version contraint, mathing 15 different versions. Please check in your composer.lock whether you are really using the latest version

Why not use any more current version of that package? v6.3.4 is from January 2024, v6.4.7 is the most current one

It need php 8, should I update my php ?

Obviously. PHP 7 ist out of support since over a year, and upgrading to PHP 8 has been recommended since years

Ok thank you, I still have a lot of stuff to do then

That's a incompatibility between the package pentatrion/vite-bundle (introduced in v6.0.0, see https://github.com/lhapaipai/vite-bundle/pull/75) and PHP 7. mixed as a return type was introduced in PHP 8, and running the code with an older PHP version throws the given error.

You have two options: if you really need to stick with PHP 7 (which is not recommended, as all kinds of support for this version have ended in Nov 2022), you could use pentatrion/vite-bundle in v5. Keep in mind that this could also limit further updates of your application, for example if you wanted to use Symfony 7. The better idea is to upgrade PHP to v8, but this could also mean that some other parts of your application need to be updated
